# variables in go templates

Tags: go, go-templates

I'm getting an error when executing the following template code:

```
{{ $total := 0 }}
{{range $i, $a := .my.vars}}
     {{ $total = (addi $total $a)}}
{{end}}
```

Here's the error: `unexpected "=" in operand`. The total variable should also change outside of the `range`, so I can't use `:=`, because it would create a new variable inside the `range` instead of increasing the `$total` variable.

The `addi` method is just a simple addition, the error does also occurr without it. It seems like the error is related to the `=` operator. If go templates don't support it, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is to define a variable type and template function to create it:

```
type variable struct {
    Value interface{}
}

func (v *variable) Set(value interface{}) string {
    v.Value = value
    return ""
}

func newVariable(initialValue interface{}) *variable {
    return &variable{initialValue}
}
```

Add it as a template function like this:

```
t.Funcs(template.FuncMap{"var": newVariable, "addi": addi})
```

Use it like this:

```
{{ $total := var 0 }}
{{range $i, $a := .vars}}
     {{$total.Set (addi $total.Value $a)}}
{{end}}
{{$total.Value}}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/bCKZOdUq1C)